# PowerShell adds int indexes of items when returning object

Tags: function, powershell, object, return

I've seen a lot of similar questions on here but none of the solutions are working for me.

I have a function that looks like this

```bsh
function Get-ManagedDevices {

    # ...(params and stuff here)...

    $batchResponse = Invoke-RestMethod @restParams
    $responses = @{}
    foreach ($response in $batchResponse.responses) {
        $responses.Add($response.id, $response.body) > $null
    }
    return , $responses
}
```

that gets called like this

```bsh
$data = Get-Devices -AccessToken $AccessToken -DeviceIds $DeviceIds
```

When I'm debugging inside of the function call I am getting what I expect when I look at the $response variable which is something like

```bsh
PS> $responses

Name                           Value
----                           -----
d1290207-c693-4663-88bf-58512… @{@odata.context=https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadat…
7ad71b70-b992-490f-8822-1561a… @{@odata.context=https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadat…

PS> $responses.count

1
```

However, when I try to use the `$data` variable from after the function call I get this

```bsh
PS> $data

0
1

Name                           Value
----                           -----
d1290207-c693-4663-88bf-58512… @{@odata.context=https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadat…
7ad71b70-b992-490f-8822-1561a… @{@odata.context=https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadat…

PS> $data.count

3
```

I'm so confused. I piped the addition of the variable to the hashtable to $null with `>$null`.
I added the unary operator with return like `return , $responses` which is what's recommended in the 'about_return' PowerShell documentation .
I tried omitting the return keyword, using an ArrayList instead, using an array instead, etc...

What on earth is going on and why can't I return a hashtable from this function?! I feel like I'm going crazy.

Comment: you seem to have left out the definition of the collection type you are `.Add()`-ing things to. i presume it is an ArrayList, tho. that ALWAYS outputs an index number when you add to it. **_the fix is to NOT use the deprecated ArrayList type._** instead, use `Generic.List`.

Comment: I hadn't heard of that being deprecated. Thank you for the tip. In this example I was just adding to the hashtable $responses. As someone else mentioned it must have been some weird session or vscode artifact because I restarted my entire setup and it's now working as expected without any of the >$null or unary operators in the return.

Comment: you are most welcome & thank you for the clarification! [*grin*]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [about_Return](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_return?view=powershell-5.1) Documentation makes no mention of returning a hash table directly from a function.  The common problem your referring to is the ability to return an array in whole rather than iterated down the pipeline.

Its common and straight forward to return a hash table. At a glance your code could be:

```
function Get-ManagedDevices {

    # ...(params and stuff here)...

    $batchResponse = Invoke-RestMethod @restParams
    $responses = @{}
    foreach ($response in $batchResponse.responses) {
        $responses.Add($response.id, $response.body)
    }
    return $responses
}
```

It shouldn't be more complicated that that. Remove the comma it has no effect when returning a hash. `>$null` has no effect on the HashTable `.Add(...)` method.

Given your results and the example, there may be some artifact from your earlier attempts using an ArrayList. The `.Add(...)` method on an ArrayList will emit the index # that it's adding to.  When we forget to `[void]` or `| Out-Null` or `$null = ...Add(...)` this usually results in unwanted output polluting the pipeline. As you're getting the 2 index numbers then your data...

Comment: Thank you. It was definitely an artifact of some sort. I restarted my computer and got some strange error messages in vscode. I reinstalled it and then took out the >$null and unary return operator and it's now working as expected. I'm glad you suggested this I thought I was going crazy.